# Writing down a symbolic logic proof of "there is a rational between two different rationals".

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

I'm still new to logic and proving so bare with me, I'll try to keep it short. I wanna write this proof entirely in symbolic form for practice reasons.

Two main questions right now: Are both the actual proof and the alternative proof correct? And for the second alternative proof did I really have to rewrite the symbolism to include an exclusive disjunction for its statement, or could I have just used the original statement but still have exclusive disjunctions in the proof and yet be valid?

\emph{Declarative statement}: Between any two different rationals there is another rational.

Symbolic form: \begin{gather*}
    \forall k_0, k_1 \in \mathbb{Q}, \exists x \in \mathbb{Q} \enspace \vert \enspace [k_0 > k_1] \wedge [k_0 > x > k_1]
\end{gather*}

Which reads as "For all rational numbers (k_0) and (k_1), where (k_0) is greater than (k_1) and x is between the two rationals (k_0) and (k_1)

\emph{Less redundancy and overall better proof}

Proof: \begin{align*}
\forall k_0, k_1 \in \mathbb{Q}, [\frac{k_0}{2} + \frac{k_1}{2}] > (2\frac{k_1}{2}) \Rightarrow \frac{k_0 + k_1}{2} > k_1 \Rightarrow [\exists x \in \mathbb{Q} \enspace \vert \enspace (\frac{(k_0 + k_1)}{2} = x)] \Rightarrow k_0 > x > k_1 \Rightarrow \enspace \text{Thus,}  \enspace x \enspace \text{is a rational that lays between \(k_0\) and \(k_1\)}.
\end{align*}

Inner proof of claim that x is a rational: x is a rational since if (k_0 = \frac{m}{n}) and (k_1 = \frac{p}{q}), then (\frac{k_0 + k_1}{2} = \frac{m(q)+p(n)}{2\cdot nq})

Rewriting the symbolic form for an alternative proof (not needed):

Symbolic form: \begin{gather*}
\forall k_0, k_1 \in \mathbb{Q}, \exists x \in \mathbb{Q} \enspace \vert \enspace [k_0 > k_1 \oplus k_1 > k_0] \wedge [k_0 > x > k_1 \oplus k_1 > x > k_0]
\end{gather*}

\emph{Alternative (longer proof, same proof kind of but with exclusive disjunctions for practiec)}

\begin{align*}
\forall k_0, k_1 \in \mathbb{Q}, [(\frac{k_0}{2} > \frac{k_1}{2}) \oplus (\frac{k_1}{2} > \frac{k_0}{2}) \wedge (k_0 \neq k_1)] \Rightarrow [\frac{k_0}{2} > \frac{k_1}{2}] \oplus [\frac{k_1}{2} > \frac{k_0}{2}] \Rightarrow [\frac{k_0}{2} + \frac{k_1}{2}] > (2\frac{k_0}{2}) \oplus (2\frac{k_1}{2}) \Rightarrow \frac{k_0 + k_1}{2} > k_0 \oplus k_1 \Rightarrow [\exists x \in \mathbb{Q} \enspace \vert \enspace (\frac{(k_0 + k_1)}{2} = x)] \Rightarrow [k_0 > x > k_1] \oplus [k_1 > x > k_0] \Rightarrow \enspace \text{Thus,}  \enspace x \enspace \text{is a rational that lays between \(k_0\) and \(k_1\)}.
\end{align*}

Inner proof of claim that x is a rational: x is a rational since if (k_0 = \frac{m}{n}) and (k_1 = \frac{p}{q}), then (\frac{k_0 + k_1}{2} = \frac{m(q)+p(n)}{2\cdot nq})

Comment: That says "every rational is unequal to every rational".

Comment: I's say $\forall a,b\in\Bbb Q:(a<b)\implies(\exists c\in\Bbb Q:a<c<b)$

Comment: Can you show me the proof you'd write to show that between two rationals there is in fact a rational?

Seems I gotta prove that the average of two rationals is also a rational, so far all I've proved seems to be that the average of two rationals is bigger than the smaller rational, but I haven't showed the average of two rationals is a rational.

Comment: The (symbolic form of the) declarative statement is not quite correct. It does not reflect the reading that you say. Use the formula given by Angina Seng in the comments. The difference is that your formula requires that $k_0 > k_1$ for any choices of $k_0$ and $k_1$ (which can not possibly be true), while Angina's formula says "For any choice of $k_0$ and $k_1$ such that $k_0 > k_1$, there exists ...".

Comment: Adding two rationals yields a rational; multiplying a rational by a rational (1/2) yields a rational. So the average of two rationals is a rational.

And, yes, @AnginaSeng's comments are correct.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I thought we can only write "such that" after an existence quantifier, rather than a for all quantifier.

e.g; \(\forall a, b \in \mathbb{Q}, a < b \Rightarrow (\exists c \in \mathbb{Q} \enspace \vert \enspace a < c < b)\)